# How do I change the UITableView drag controls and behavior?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to use the the dragging functionality that UITableView offers while in editing mode to rearrange some custom views in the cell.contentView. I am successfully getting editing mode turned on after a long press on the cell and turned off following a reorder.

Here is a picture of how I have things set up: http://cl.ly/image/081k3G0A3f2I

The problems I have are:

1. The contentView indents no matter what I set ShouldIndentWhileEditing to.
2. I would like to get rid of the delete control and the drag control.
3. The whole contentView should be the drag area instead of just the little drag control area.

Help with this would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize the look of the drag controls. Try overriding `layoutSubviews`. In that method, check for editing status and draw /position your elements accordingly.

Comment: Could you share more detail on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: This would require digging into the private view structure of a cell. Any such attempt is fragile and potentially dangerous.

Comment: @maddy Not necessary. In layoutSubviews you can insert a view covering the drag controls.

Comment: IIRC I managed this by iterating over the subviews, picking the reorder control by class name, either setting `hidden=YES` or `alpha=0` (I forget), and forwarding touch events to it so you can drag anywhere in the cell. Likely to break across OS releases, so remember to test this on early betas so you have time to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the drag control if you have enable row reordering. The API does not allow any customization of row reordering. The only solution would be your own custom table type view.

You can get rid of the delete control. Simply return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` from the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Comment: Would overriding layoutSubviews like Mundi suggests not work to change the reordering drag control? How would I go about implementing a custom table type view?

Comment: I don't suggest digging into the private subview layout of `UITableViewCell`. Writing your own table view is a huge topic and can't be answered in a SO post.

Comment: When you say, "write your own table view," do you mean re-implementing the functionality of UITableView completely?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Certainly not an easy task but it would give you complete control.